# Is there a way to get rectangle points on an image which has an white rectangle with black color drawing

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to get four coordinates on an image which has an white rectangle with black color drawing.

[image]

I'v tried the extreme point technic from opencv

```
leftmost = tuple(contour[contour[:,:,0].argmin()][0])
rightmost = tuple(contour[contour[:,:,0].argmax()][0])
topmost = tuple(contour[contour[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
bottommost = tuple(contour[contour[:,:,1].argmax()][0])
```

but I got below image

[image]

However What I really want is the every vertex of a white rectangle.

[image]

Is there a way to get the four red points?

Comment: "extreme point" technique? why do you think that's useful here? check out adjacent tutorials. you want a `minAreaRect` perhaps

Comment: Also check that you're only extracting a single contour (or if not, use the largest one).